# Grails Dynamic Rest Endpoint Mapping

Tags: grails

In my UrlMappings I have this mapping defined :

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{}
```

and now I want to add a set of version 2 services.

for example :
A new service at URI : `/api/myaction`

and I want to be able define  a new endpoint `/api/v2/myaction` , where *myaction* will map to a new action called *myactionV2*

Comment: I didn't get what the problem is...

Comment: The ask is to define a new url mapping to allow API versioning while at the same time preserving the dynamic nature of mapping so developers can added controllers on the fly.  I'm thinking something like this : "/$controller/$version/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{}  but that doesn't quite work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this and the best solution depends on some factors that you haven't included in your question.  Here is a solution that most closely maps to the question and a comment that the OP added above.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/javaheadendpoints.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/javaheadendpoints/blob/47f41b3943422c3c9e44a08ac646ecb2046972d1/grails-app/controllers/demo/v1/ApiController.groovy

```
package demo.v1

class ApiController {
    static namespace = 'v1'

    def myaction() {
        render 'This request was handled by version 1 of the api'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/javaheadendpoints/blob/47f41b3943422c3c9e44a08ac646ecb2046972d1/grails-app/controllers/demo/v2/ApiController.groovy

```
package demo.v2

class ApiController {
    static namespace = 'v2'

    def myaction() {
        render 'This request was handled by version 2 of the api'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/javaheadendpoints/blob/47f41b3943422c3c9e44a08ac646ecb2046972d1/grails-app/controllers/demo/v3/ApiController.groovy

```
package demo.v3

class ApiController {
    static namespace = 'v3'

    def myaction() {
        render 'This request was handled by version 3 of the api'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/javaheadendpoints/blob/47f41b3943422c3c9e44a08ac646ecb2046972d1/grails-app/controllers/javaheadendpoints/UrlMappings.groovy

```
package javaheadendpoints

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/$controller/$namespace/$action/$id?(.$format)?" {
            // ...
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

Sending requests yields what I think is the requested behavior:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/myaction
This request was handled by version 1 of the api
$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v2/myaction
This request was handled by version 2 of the api
$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v3/myaction
This request was handled by version 3 of the api
```

Other options include using a `Version` http header but because of some of the wording above, I think that is not going to be exactly what you want.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

not suppose to do that,The way i suggest is to split in two controller

```
/api1/myaction
```

```
/api2/myaction
```

or in action

```
/api/myaction1
```

```
/api/myaction2
```

Comment: The question explicitly states "...and I want to be able define a new endpoint `/api/v2/myaction`".  I don't think this answer provides a solution that addresses that request.